# Remapping image to different size and finding pixel location

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am implementing an algorithm in which i have to use multi resolution analysis. What that paper says is that i have to perform some processing at lower scale, find some pixel locations and then remap the pixels according to the orignal scale. I really dont understand the remapping function in Open cv. If any one could help me that would be great. 
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very vague. Post whatever code you have written so far related to this part of the process and also a link a to the algorithm in question.

Comment: Check out this tutorial, it's pretty well explained what OpenCV's `remap`function does. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap

Comment: Suppose there is an image of resolution x,y with a pixel location (x1,y1). i have resized that image to double resolution i.e. 2x, 2y. Now i want to find out the region which will correspond to orignal pixel location (x1,y1).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize picture in OpenCV, you can do this:

```
Mat img = imread(picturePath, CV_8UC1);
Mat resized(NEW_HEIGH, NEW_WIDTH, CV_32FC1);
img.convertTo(img, CV_32FC1);
resize(img, resized, resized.size());
```

If you want to acess a specific pixel, use:

```
img.at<var>(row, col)
```

in a CV_32FC1 format replace "var" with "float", for CV_8UC1 replace with "int"

Hope this will help.